# percentage of winning this kind of raffle

Tags: probability, statistics

I enjoy my fair bit of mathematics and I have a question for you guys. I play this game where users try to win prizes in a raffle. The raffle works as follows:
The raffle resets when all 9 prizes are won, or when users clicked to play in the raffle 200 times. Thus, the raffle starts out with 200/200, meaning you have 200 times to play the raffle. However, there are only 9 prizes, so if someone plays the raffle 5 times and wins nothing, the raffle now shows 195/200 and 9 available prizes left. If someone wins a prize on the 6th try, then the raffle reads 194/200 and 8 available prizes.

Here is where my question comes into play:
When I played the raffle, it was 75/200 with 7 prizes left to win. So I wanted to calculated my percentage of winning a prize if I played the raffle 25 times. How would one calculate this percentage? The chance of winning a prize keeps on changing because my first try is 7/75, my next try is 7/74 (assuming I don't win the first time), then 7/73, and so on. Would my percentage of winning be 7/75 + 7/74 + 7/73 + ...... + 7/51? I did this on an excel spreadsheet and got a 281% chance of winning. Does this mean that I would expect to win 2 prizes? If this is not the case, could you please explain why my logic is wrong over here, because I am really interested in this. Thank you for reading!

Comment: What are the chances of winning a prize on any given attempt? Do all nine prizes have to be won?

Comment: Is the idea that there are basically 200 "raffle tickets", and 9 of them are chosen at random to be winning tickets?

Comment: Yes, Jack M has it right. and all 9 prizes have to be won

Comment: You might do better by looking at the probability of not winning a prize and subtracting from $1$

Comment: Your expected number of prizes to win is $25 \times 7 / 75 \approx 2.333$

Comment: yeah thats what I did on the excel spreadsheets, I just did 7/75 + 7/74 + .... + 7/51. Is it really that simple? I thought that the probability can never be greater than 1, so I thought that I was wrong. This seems wrong though because I can win no prizes, so how do I find the PERCENTAGE of winning 1 prize in 25 tries, when it starts out as 7 prizes left with 75 raffles left

Answer (score 0):

We have $200$ tickets, of which $9$ are chosen uniformly to be winning tickets.

When you're down to the last $75$ with $7$ prizes left, you have a $7/75$ chance of winning a prize on the next attempt. If you fail, then you do indeed have a $7/74$ chance of winning a prize on your second attempt. However, this does not mean that your chances of winning a prize on the first two attempts is $\frac 7 {75} + \frac 7 {74}$. After all, when you toss a coin twice, you don't have a $50\%+50\%=100\%$ chance of getting heads one of the times.

Instead, your odds of winning nothing over the first two attempts is the *product* of your odds of winning nothing on the two individual attempts, that is, $\frac{68}{75}\frac{67}{74}$. Your odds of winning *something* are therefore $1-\frac{68}{75}\frac{67}{74}$. Over $25$ attempts, your odds of winning something are similarly $1-\frac{68}{75}\frac{67}{74}...\frac{43}{50}$

This is because failing on the first attempt and failing on the second attempt are *independent*. This is easier to understand with coin flips. Your odds of getting two heads when flipping a coin twice is the product of the odds of getting a head on each attempt: $0.5\cdot 0.5=0.25$. This is because, *of* the times when you get a head on the first attempt, you will get heads on the second attempt *half* the time, thus in total you get two heads half of half the time, or a quarter of the time. If the answer were anything else, that would mean the coin flips somehow influenced each other, for example, if of the times you got heads on the first attempt you got heads on the second attempt $70\%$ of the time, that would mean that getting heads on the first attempt somehow increases the odds of getting heads on the second attempt.

Comment: WOW! WHAT A GREAT READ! That was very clear and so good! I thank you very much. I just have a follow up question. "Instead, your odds of winning nothing over the first two attempts is the product of your odds of winning nothing on the two individual attempts, that is, (68/75) * (67/74)." Could you please explain why this is the case, why multiplying the failures will give you the odds of winning nothing intuitively. Also, can I then say that (7/75) * (7/74) will give me the chance of winning in 2 tries. It makes so much more sense when reading your explanation with the coins!

Comment: @Sean Did you understand the third paragraph? Just think of each attempt as throwing a coin, and losing as getting heads. You'll lose the second time $67/75$ of the times you lost on the first attempt, etc. The same thing doesn't work for calculating the chances of winning in $2$ tries, but it does work for calculating the chances of winning *both* times. You have to work it out by saying that your chances of winning at least once are $100\%$ minus your odds of losing every time, then apply the logic of paragraph three to work out the odds of losing every time.

Comment: Oh!!! It accounts for winning both times because the first time you have a 7/75 chance to win then assuming you got there, you then have a 6/74 chance to win based on the 7/75 chance you won before, so it is (7/75) * (6/74) to win twice in 2 tries?

Comment: @Sean $(7/75)*(7/74)$ won't tell you anything useful. However, $(7/75)*(6/74)$ would tell you the odds of winnings twice in a row.  In essence, this sort of problem becomes easier when you stop thinking of "How likely am I to win?" and start thinking "How likely am I to not lose?"

Comment: So we have a way of approaching this problem of "how likely am I to not lose" Basically 1 - prob of losing. Lets assume now I just want to know how likely I am to win a prize in only two attempts. Its 1 - (68/75)*(67/74) = .179, how can I get this same answer, 0.179, in terms of looking at it from a "how likely am i to win" approach? It makes so much sense/easier to view it from 1 - odds of losing, however is there a way to reach our answer from looking at a winning perspective?

Comment: @Sean Your chances of winning are equal to the chances of winning the first time *and* losing the second time, plus the chances of winning the second time *and* losing the first time, plus the chances of winning both times. You can work this out using the same logic, and you should again get  0.179.

Comment: Wow! I really cannot thank you enough, you know what you're talking about and explain it so CLEARLY! Can you just make sense of one more thing for me please. Henry said that "Your expected number of prizes to win is 25×7/75≈2.333" in the comments above. This does make sense to me logically, is this a true or false statement? And if it is true, then how does it work with the percentage we would have found by doing 1 - (68/75)(67/74)....(43/50). Say 1 - (68/75)(67/74)....(43/50) = 82%, this means that i have an 82% chance of winning ATLEAST one prize, but I can expect 2.333 prizes?

Comment: @Sean Yes, it's correct. It can be worked out from the odds that we calculated, but that would be very tedious. You would have to calculate 1 times the odds of winning (exactly) one prize, two times the odds of winning two prizes, 3 times the odds of winning three, and so on up to the odds of winning all seven, and add all of those up. Henry's logic was to add up the odds of the first attempt winning plus the odds of the second attempt winning and so on, which works due to a property called linearity of expected value which is too complicated to explain in a comment.

Comment: @Sean when he says expected, he means "If you call those 25 raffle tickets a single run, and you did a million runs (so 25 million tickets total, always starting at 75 left or whatever) you'd get an average of 2.333 prizes per run." So some runs you'd get a all 7 of the prizes! Some runs you'd get NONE of the prizes. On average, you'd expect 2.333.

Comment: thanks for all the answers guys, this was really helpful!